# When is ActionBar coming to support library

Tags: android

When I was at Google I/O they said they were adding ActionBar to the support library but so far I haven't seen this happen.
It got the biggest cheer of all the announcements at the conference :)
Does anyone know when this is going to be added?

Comment: Use http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: Shouldn't need to use third party libraries, should be part of Android.

Comment: In that case you should wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find out when everyone else finds out, if and when it ships. Google does not announce timetables for future software releases in Android.